# Start a method with keyword arguments as a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'd like to start this method as a thread:

```
server.run('0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

This is how I do it without the keyword argument:

```
start_new_thread(server.run, ('0.0.0.0', None, False))
```

This is my ugly solution:

```
def startServer():
     server.run('0.0.0.0', threaded=True)

start_new_thread(startServer, ())
```

Can this be done in one line?

Comment: I edited your code's layout to conform to the readability standards in [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `start_new_thread` has no `**kwargs` argument then you can use:

```
from functools import partial
start_new_thread(partial(server.run, "0.0.0.0", threaded=True))
```

Or simply:

```
start_new_thread(server.run, ("0.0.0.0",), {"threaded": True})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It [looks like](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) `start_new_thread` has `kwargs`. How can I use them?